# Large DFA examples?

Tags: fsm, dfa

I am doing some research on DFA optimization, which needs several large DFA examples with inputs.

I tried to program a DFA generator, with which the results would be artificial.

Do you, by any chance, know some large DFAs or FSMs which I can refer to?

Comment: You can make some very very large DFAs from regexs. Can you be a bit more specific about what you want?

Comment: @DanielWilliams As long as they are real (used by people) regexs with inputs, it would be great. Could you share some links with me?

Comment: @JackWM what do you mean by **optimization** ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan This optimization is to let the DFA simulation become faster.